# Can someone say what went wrong in this code?

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a problem which takes a nums, row, column as parameters and returns a resultant matrix of size row x column.

```
def matrixReshape(self, nums, r, c):
    """
    :type nums: List[List[int]]
    :type r: int
    :type c: int
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    count = 0
    i = j = 0
    m = [[0]*c]*r
    for row in nums:
        for val in row:
            if j < c and i < r:
                print(val,m[i][j], i, j)
                m[i][j] = val
                print(val,m[i][j], i, j)
                count += 1
                j += 1
                if j == c:
                    i += 1
                    j = 0  
    if count == (r*c):
        return m
    else:
        return nums
```

When I tested for input like ([[1,2],[3,4]], 4, 1) it generates output [[4],[4],[4],[4]] instead of [[1],[2],[3],[4]]

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that has meaning. It should describe the problem or question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future reader here who is looking at it in a list of search results. Your current title has zero meaning. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m = [[0]*c]*r
```

This creates a list of `r` references to the same inner list. So, whenever you modify `m[0]`, you're also modifying `m[1]`, and so on, because they're the same list.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
m = [[0 for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[0]*4` gives you four copies of the *same* object, not four independent lists.

Try

```
m = [[0 for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
```